# How to add a foreign key to ApplicationUser between separate project in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

There is a Blazor WebAssembly Application with Asp.Net Core Hosting in .NET 5.0.0, which is separate to 3 different projects: `WebApp.Client`, `WebApp.Server`, `WebApp.Shared`.

And I'm using `AspNetCore.Identity` and `IdentityServer4` to manage my application users.

But the class `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` is in `WebApp.Server` project, while my model class `Foo` is in `WebApp.Shared` project. (The `WebApp.Server` project has the reference of `WebApp.Shared` project so that `Foo` can't `using WebApp.Server.Models`.)

Can I add a foreign key to `ApplicationUser` class between separate project? Or can I move `ApplicationUser` to `WebApp.Shared` project?

#### Code

```cs
// WebApp.Server.Models.ApplicationUser

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
// WebApp.Shard.Models.Foo
public class Foo
{
    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; } // CS0246 
}
```

Comment: You cant have a biderectional relationship, can you explain the context you are trying to do this? maybe there is a better alternative

Comment: @nalnpir The Foo is a kind of activity. I want to record which user is attend this activity and which activity the user attend from two tables.

Comment: you could actually move the model itself to the Shared part.. and you could get away with it. I dont know why something that should be consumed by the server would be in the shared section. My thinking to be honest is you should probably reconsider your architecture

Comment: @nalnpir I agree with you. Perhaps I need to reconstruct my solution because it's really confusing now.

Comment: It's good to move your shared classes to a shared project if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way without many dependencies is :

// WebApp.Shard.Models.Foo

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Foo<TUser>
{
    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ApplicationUserId))]
    public virtual TUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple foreign key like `AApplicationUserId`, `BApplicationUserId`?

Comment: @DCTewi You would have to describe the user <==> foo relationship your after in a bit more detail please?.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the lack of detail and thank you for your help. I found that my architecture is too bad and confusing. So I will reconstruct my project with a simple model relationship.